# Format Date and Time in .NET

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How to format date and time to local system date and time format? I need to format date and time separately. Suppose date is "06/11/2013" and time is "16:00:00" now both need to be formatted to system current date format and time format (with am/pm if 12 hours mode).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.ToString()` takes a string format parameter that allows you to create whatever format you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

If you use `DateTime.Now` to get the current date/time of the server you can then use the `.ToString()` method to format your output.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Globalization;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```